# Uncaught Error: A network error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

after I've tried to use the firebase authentication service, I got an `uncaught error: a network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred`

I have tried to whitelist all related domain-names:

```
  <allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com" />
  <allow-intent href="*.firebaseapp.com" />
  <allow-intent href="*.google.com" />
  <allow-intent href="*.googleapis.com" />
  <allow-intent href="*.cloudflare.com" />
  <allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com" />
  <access origin="*" />
```

and ask for internet user permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

but still - despite the code run perfectly on web browser, it keep showing this error on the android emulator.

Comment: hey @aviran-mor any chance you found a solution? I think I'm hitting the same thing with latest ionic (3.0.0) and latest firebase (3.7.6)

Answer (score 0):

try, this.  it worked for me.

```
<allow-navigation href="*.firebaseapp.com" />
```