# New User not saved in Firebase using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, general-network-error

i am working in angular and want to add new user in Firebase, everything work fine without any error but when i open firebase Database it didn't show any data and show error in console

**FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/zJJNe15WyDW0TYh5L2khIp9BeH62 failed: permission_denied**

after changing Rules `allow read, write: if true;` then error change to

**Uncaught Error: Network Error**

[image: Empty Firebase Database]

here is service through which i want to add new user

```
export class UserService {    
  constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase) { }    
  save(user : firebase.User)
  {
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
      name : user.displayName,
      email : user.email
    });
  }
}
```

And here is imports of this service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

and this is app.component

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private userService: UserService ,private auth : AuthService, private router :Router)
  {
    auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
      if (user)
      {
        userService.save(user);

        let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
        router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

i use firebase for logging in which work perfectly and other functionality also work fine but here it is not saving new user in firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `set` to **create** a document - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document

You use `update` to **update** fields - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data

Try:

```
save(user : firebase.User)
  {
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).set({
      name : user.displayName,
      email : user.email
    });
  }
```

**Edit**: It seems that you were experiencing "Uncaught Error: Network Error". This may be resolved by following this question - [Uncaught Error: A network error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109545/uncaught-error-a-network-error)

Comment: @Raza Do you see any errors in the console? Have you set up the rules correctly for that path so that **write** is allowed?

Comment: Yeah i change rule for firebase database (allow read, write: if true;) and still not working and showing error Uncaught Error: Network Error

Comment: @Raza Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109545/uncaught-error-a-network-error

Comment: Thank you dude now i am able to add new user in firebase

Comment: @Raza Cool. I've added the extra info to the answer.